# How can I stop bluetile from changing the window manager theme?

Tags: themes, compiz, window-manager, metacity

When I start [bluetile](http://www.bluetile.org/) it replaces the current theme of the window manager. How can I keep the current theme and settings, and still use bluetile?

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading the bluetile site properly, it is a window manager itself, so when you load it, it replaces your window manager, which is where your theme is coming from.  If you watch the video he explains the theme, the buttons have been modified to fit in with the tiling aspect of things.

thats my guess at least.

Comment: You're partially right: bluetile is a window manager on its own, and it doesn't include a theming engine currently, so you're left with whatever basic "theme" he created for his proof of concept implementation.  AFAIK the theme wasn't modified/designed to fit with tiling though.  And it's possible to extend BlueTile to support e.g. GNOME/Metacity themes, but somebody will have to take the time & effort to do that...